# When writing my own document class, certain options don't get passed to base class. Why?

Tags: table-of-contents, biblatex, koma-script, documentclass-writing, class-options

I'm trying to create my own class using `scrbook` as a base class, and `biblatex` as for my bibliography. Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc,fontsize=12]{scrbook}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@book{electrodynamics,
    Author={Eringen, A.C. and Maugin, G.A.},
    Title={Electrodynamics of Continua},
    Year={1990}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\bibliography{refs}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This works as expected, i.e. the bibliography shows up in the ToC. Now, my seemingly equivalent self-made class

```
\ProvidesClass{myclass}

\LoadClass[
    bibliography=totoc,
    fontsize=12
    ]{scrbook}

\RequirePackage{biblatex}
```

used like so

```
\documentclass{myclass}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@book{electrodynamics,
    Author={Eringen, A.C. and Maugin, G.A.},
    Title={Electrodynamics of Continua},
    Year={1990}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{refs}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

does not have a bibliography entry in the ToC. The fontsize option (and almost all the others I've tried) get passed as expected. What's going on?

Comment: Does it work with the option `toc=bibliography` (or `toc=bib`)?

Comment: No, it doesn't. At least not on my system (current TeXLive 2012 btw).

Comment: The global options are those passed to `\documentclass`, not those passed to `\LoadClass`.

Answer (score 4):

While I don't have a clue why this happens, here's a workaround: change your class to

```
\ProvidesClass{myclass}

\LoadClass[
    fontsize=12
    ]{scrbook}

\PassOptionsToPackage{bibliography=totoc}{biblatex}

\RequirePackage{biblatex}
```

Comment: Need to look pg 364 source2e.pdf You need to use '\LoadClassWithOptions' or '\PassOptionsToClass'.